# What does this sentence mean: "Was the Colonel waved his paper yet?"

Tags: meaning

I found this sentence in Collins COBUILD English Grammar.

"Was the Colonel waved his paper yet?"

I have no clue about what it could mean. 
Grammar-wise, it looks totally messed up. 
Is it me not getting something here or might that be an odd sort of error on the publisher's side?

Comment: It means somebody screwed up somewhere, because the sentence makes no sense.

Comment: @Robusto - One-character typo, perhaps? Change that leading "W" to an "H": _Has the Colonel waved his paper yet?_

Comment: I rest my case. Somebody did screw up somewhere.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's based on a misprint of the original

Answer (score 5):

Yes, that is a typo.

The original sentence was:

> Has the colonel waved his paper yet?

It is from [*The Day of the Jackal*](https://books.google.nl/books?id=617EJvZpAfQC&pg=PT20&dq=has+the+colonel+waved+his+paper+yet&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CCEQ6AEwAGoVChMIqte2_a_vxwIVRLQaCh1VMQNg#v=onepage&q=has%20the%20colonel%20waved%20his%20paper%20yet&f=false) by *Frederick Forsyth*.